# webpack entry point js scripts not loaded

Tags: webpack

I've created a `dist` using `webpack`. It seems files (chunks, source maps, assets) are created correctly on this folder.

I've three entry points set on my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
...
entry: {

  'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
  'vendor':    './src/vendor.browser.ts',
  'main':      './src/main.browser.ts'

},
...
```

So, on my `index.html` the content is:

```
<html>
...
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`dist` folder is located on `D:\projects\living\user-platform/project/dist`.

So, when I load my `index.html` locally: `file:///D:/projects/living/user-platform/project/dist/index.html` I've realized scripts are not loaded since browser is trying to get them using `D:\-like` paths: `D:\polyfills.bundle.js`, `D:\vendor.bundle.js`and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to serv this app via like https://www.npmjs.com/package/single-page-server   instead of directly load.

Comment: Thanks. It seems cool. I've just installed it using `npm install single-page-server`. Nevertheless, I'm not able how to make work it. Which command would I set in order to it works? (my files are under `dist` folder)

Comment: single-page-server -p=3000 -b=. -f=./dist/index.html  
try run this command on folder that parent of dist.  
your app will be serving on localhost:3000

Comment: I've tried it: `single-page-server -p=3000 -b=dist -f=dist/index.html`. It's telling me: _Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\dist\index'_. It seems it's trying to get `dist\index` instead of `dist/index.html`

Comment: -b=. or -b=./  instead of -b=dist